# Why do we resize the image to half the size in the SIFT algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, sift

In the construction of the scale space of SIFT algorithm, we progressively halve the size of the image and then get a series of blurred images for each size.

My question is, how does `halving the image size` while constructing the `scale space` help in the SIFT algorithm?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, these are two questions:

1. What is the reason for reducing the image size
2. Why is the image reduced by factor 2

As for the first question: In order to calculate the sift features we need to convolve the image with Gauss kernels for different sigma-parameters. When the sigma-parameters are small, this kernel is not that big (because it becomes almost 0 very fast as the distance to the middle increases). However the sigma parameter increases exponentially during the analysis and thus also the kernel size needed for precise calculations. Increasing the size of the Gauss kernel means increasing the calculation time. On the other hand, after the convolution with the Gauss kernel, the higher frequencies in the image spectrum are almost erased - the is no gain in keeping a higher resolution, because the are no details left on this level.

So reducing the size of the image eliminates the need for bigger kernels without paying any price at the cost of the precision.

So why to reduce the image by factor 2? We could use any other factor, but

1. Factor 2 is better than factor 1.5, because it is much easier to calculate the resulting image - there is no need for interpolation.
2. Factor 2 is better than factor 3, because in the case of 3 we would need bigger Gauss kernels: for sigma-parameter 3 compared to maximal sigma-parameter 2 if we reduce the image by factor 2.

**Edit:** As Yves pointed out, we not only don't have to calculate more for larger sigma parameters, we have to calculate less, because the image becomes smaller after each rescaling (which we can do without loss of precision, because convolution with Gauss kernel eliminates the higher frequencies in the image).

Comment: I agree with your argument, anyway there are constant-time implementations of the Gaussian convolution which make the large kernels feasible. A stronger reason is that a scale-space representation takes MN² pixels (where M is the number of resolutions), while a dyadic pyramid doesn't exceed 4N²/3 pixels for any M.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks, I was not aware of such constant time convolutions, could you please give a link for it?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I also didn't think of the memory consumption. Yet if one is only interested in the sift features, only 3 levels of resolution are needed simultaneously - the memory can be reused over and over again.

Comment: no, not the memory consumption, the computation time. [Unfortunately, time cannot be reused over and over.] "Recursive Gaussian Derivative Filters, L. van Vliet & al.", and "“Recursively implementing the Gaussian and its derivatives, R. Deriche" are the most commonly used.